# The form of the surface $z(x,y)$

Tags: relations, 3d, surfaces, regression

In $3$D space, we have

For any fixed $x$, $z$ is of the form: $z=ay+b$

For any fixed $y$, $z$ is of the form: $z=c \ln(x) +d$

---

In other words, we have

$z(x=\text{constant},y)=A(x)y+B(x)$, and

$z(x,y=\text{constant})=C(y) \ln(x)+D(y)$

where $A(x),B(x),C(y),D(y)$ are constants

---

> What could be the form of the equation of the surface $z(x,y)$?

---

See [my related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3405437/x-y-z-regression-linear-and-logarithmic-relaions)

---

Any help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Doesn't JJacquelin's answer, in combination with Hussain-Alqatari's comment, already answer this?

Comment: @MattiP. Actually I do not know how did he combine them. I tried to understand. My issue now is only the combination.

Comment: It seems like $z(x,y)=k_1y\log(x)+k_2y+k_3\log(x)+k_4$ is fine.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like $$z(x,y)=k_1y\log(x)+k_2y+k_3\log(x)+k_4$$ is fine. Compare to your functions $A,B,C,D$, $$A(x)=k_1\log(x)+k_2\\ B(x)=k_3\log(x)+k_4\\ C(y)=k_1y+k_3\\ D(y)=k_2y+k_4.$$

Comment: From the data given by Hussain-Alqatari  : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406880/the-form-of-the-surface-zx-y  the regression calculus with $z(x,y)=k_1y\log(x)+k_2y+k_3\log(x)+k_4$ gives $k_1=0.000503\quad k_2= 0.009197\quad k_3=0.465157 \quad k_4=-3.322476$ . Result of fitting : RMS Error$\simeq 0.2$ and RMS Relative Error$\simeq 19$% .

Comment: @JJacquelin The data are NOT part of this question.

Comment: Of course, this was a complement of information. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @edm Thanks dear, I tried in many ways, I still did not understand why $z(x,y)=k_{1}y \ln(x) + k_{2}y+ k_{3} \ln(x) + k_{4}$. I tried to use this expression ,, YES, it gave good estimates for some $z$'s .. but please dear ,, explain how did you get that form?

Answer (score 0):

By two equations we have (I have no exact proof):
$$A(x)y = C(y)\ln(x) \Longrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{c} A(x) = e\ln(x) \\ C(y) = ey \\ \end{array}\right\}$$
$$B(x) = D(y) \Longrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{c} B'_x(x) = D'_x(y) = 0 \\ D'_y(y) = B'_y(x) = 0 \\ \end{array}\right\} \Longrightarrow B(x) = D(y) = f$$
Such that $e,f$ are constant. So:
$$z(x,y) = ey\ln(x)+f$$
To finding $e,f$ you need two point that $z$ was given.

Comment: Why to say $A(x)y=C(y) \ln(x)$?

Comment: I said "I have no exact proof". But it make an answer. Although the general answer may has other possibilities.